# disable facebox links until page loads

Tags: facebox, disable-link

I would like to disable my facebox links until the page has completely loaded reason being, when I click on a facebox link before the page loads completely, the page loads a different page instead of the modal! What is the best way to fix this problem?

This is facebox script

```
<link href="facebox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
        loading_image : 'images/ajax-loading.gif',
        close_image   : 'images/fb_closelabel.png'
      }) 
    })
</script>
```

this is html

```
<a href="linktosomewhere.php" rel="facebox">Click to goto somewhere</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.hover1{font-size:10pt};

$(function(e){
  $(".hover1").attr('href','');
});
// here you can change the path in 'http://www.viomjeet.blogspot.com'


<a href="http://www.google.co.in">click to google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var blocking = false;

$(window).load(function(){blocking=true;});

$('a').click(function(){return blocking});
```

So... the links wont be clickable till all the images have loaded which is fired on window.load(...)

modify $('a') to your facebox links

Comment: hey samccone, thanx for this but where do I place this script? anywhere?

Comment: just in the header wrapped in script tags.. it uses jquery so you need to have it as well ...

Comment: facebox links use the attribute rel so can I just do $('a rel')?

Comment: Post the code around markup around a face box you will have to do something like .facebox>a or something hard to say with no code

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out a decent workaround.  Depending on the content you're dealing with, a simple solution is to set display:none to the  tag in question, then simply add the following code to your js.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
    loading_image : 'images/ajax-loading.gif',
    close_image   : 'images/fb_closelabel.png'
  });
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').show();  

})
```

and in your html:

```
 <a href="linktosomewhere.php" rel="facebox" style="display:none;">Click to goto somewhere</a>
```

A few months late, but hope this helps someone!

Comment: hello butangphp, if I do this, it means the element will be hidden till the page loads??? But I just want the link to be disabled till the page loads...isn't there away to do this so that when you click on the link it won't work till the page is loaded??

Answer (score 0):

Jay,

In response to your question, here's how I manage to have the link display, but not function until all the content is loaded:

JS:

```
$("a.add-facebox").click(function(){
        $.facebox({ ajax: $(this).attr('fb-href') });
        return false
});
```

HTML:

```
 <a href="#" class="add-facebox" fb-href="linktosomewhere.php">Click to go somewhere</a>
```

Hope this helps!